# Query to search data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables,one containing specific text keyword in one column and another table with large text in a column, each having distinct number of records.
I want to write a query to check whether text field in second table contains any of keyword from 1st table.
I want to check all my keywords with all the records of 2nd table's text field.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show that you've tried something.

Comment: I tried: select column1 from table1,table2 where column1 like '%'+table2.column+'%'                                                  but didn't get the desired output.

Comment: can you give us some sample data of what you have and what you want to see?

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `LIKE` clause in the `JOIN`.  See [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9d20d/1)

```
SELECT *
FROM TableTwo t2
JOIN TableOne t1 ON t2.ColumnOne LIKE '%' + t1.ColumnOne + '%'
```